# Replacing main lights throughout house

Tags: wiring

I'm replacing the main lights throughout the house and was removing a wire from the junction box the light came with.

The wire was 100% jammed in and this metal casing came off. See pictured below)

[image]
[image]

Can I place the barewire into the junction box or will I have to struggle getting the casing off the old light wiring and put onto new light?

[image]

Comment: If it is a brand new light fixture you should return it and get a replacement that doesn't have this flaw.

Comment: If you need to use it at all (depends on the terminal block) don't "pry it off the old wire end" - go buy a new one and crimp it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your 3rd picture. Unfortunately, the end will have to go back on for a secure connection. I'd put this one aside for now & get the rest of the lights done. Primarily to see if any of the other lights have similar issues & secondly to give you time to consider wrestling with it/them or just exchanging it/them at the store.

Comment: This is the crown in question

http://imgur.com/AZtzUE1

sorry for image link again, it got edited for me last time :/

Comment: Ah, that does make a difference. Yeah, the end would have to go back on in order for the wiring harness to make a secure connection. If you have a bunch of lights, put this one aside until the end. So, you can get the rest done & decide if it's worth wrestling or just swapping at the store.

Comment: Perfect thanks for the response. Ill have a go at wrestling it off the old one, but it will take a while as its quite stiff and fiddly.

Comment: Yep, those are quite tough little buggers. You might want to wear heavy gloves, the tiny precision screw driver will sink into you like a knife.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is the *rating* on that **terminal block**.  Is it *rated* for bare stranded wire?   If so, just discard the ferrule (that's a ferrule), strip the wire back and go.

Fixture makers are required to supply those things on new CE rated fixtures, and I can see where they play well with Euro style terminal blocks. It's not clear to me whether the installer is required to use them; if so, that would be "basics" and every shop would sell the ferrules and correct crimp tool.

In America, we just cut them off.  I get fixtures all the time from China with very flimsy ferrules, and they are incompatible with our primary splicing method: the wire-nut.